# Send POST parameters with Retrofit

Tags: android, post, retrofit

I am trying to implement a POST request via Retrofit, but the approach seems to be wrong, I guess. I followed the steps I used for GET request:

I defined the end point:

```
 public interface GitHubEmailAPI {

    @POST("/users/{user}")
    Call<GitHubEmail> postEmail(@Field("email") String email);
}
```

The model:

```
    public class GitHubEmail {

    @SerializedName("email")
    private String email;

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

And the calling:

```
 public void postEmail (){
    GitHubEmailAPI apiService =
            ApiClient.getClient().create(GitHubEmailAPI.class);

    final Call<GitHubEmail> callEmail = apiService.postEmail
            (String.valueOf(enterEmailEt.getText()));

    callEmail.enqueue(new Callback<GitHubEmail>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<GitHubEmail> call, Response<GitHubEmail> response) {
            testTV.setText(callEmail.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<GitHubEmail> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("Email", t.toString());

        }
    });
```

I am using the github api as a test, not sure if the access token needs to be included as a parameter in the request.

Comment: Is your doubt is clear ??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are some info which you know about Retrofit ....

> 1. Your BASE_URL must be end with / .
> 2. When you using `@Field` notation you must put `@FormUrlEncoded` in Your Api call.
> 3. When you using {user} in the API method you have to use `@Path("user") String user` to relate to url data .
> 4. Your POST method URL will be like this `@POST("users/{user}")`.
> 5. When your response Callback done the **actual Data** inside your `Response<GitHubEmail> response` in this variable. You have to use `response.body()` to get what you get response from API CALL.

Here is a sample code

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("users/{user}")
Call<YourResultPojoClassHere> yourFuntionName(@Field("id") String id,@Path("user") String path);
```

please take look on below code ....

```
callEmail.enqueue(new Callback<GitHubEmail>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<GitHubEmail> call, Response<GitHubEmail> response) {
              if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        if (response.body().getSuccess()) 

                            Toast.makeText(ClassName.this, response.body().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        else
                            Toast.makeText(ClassName.this, response.body().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else 
                        Toast.makeText(ClassName.this, "Sorry for inconvince server is down", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<GitHubEmail> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(ClassName.this, "Check your Internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @sushildlh!

Comment: after I implemented what you advised me to do, the body of the response is null, the error body saying "Not found". What about putting an access token, for example? Or it means, that the path is wrong?

Comment: will you please share url ? **OR** In the beckhend you have to handle your data and response .....

Comment: this one is GET request .....instead of POST just use GET **AND** handle your response using POJO.

Comment: I want to post an email if no such available, I need GET for this?

Comment: the above link your shared is GET response ... For Posting email you have to create POST response in beck-end . Use POSTMAN to identified all the RESTAPI . You have another POST request then please share .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124096/discussion-between-sushildlh-and-user6456773).

Comment: Thank you for your exaplanations! I'll handle it from here on

Answer (score 6):

For POST in retrofit you must include `@FormUrlEncoded`

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("path_here")
Call<ResponseBody> function_name(@Field("data") String data);
```